# Angular Js: Factory, Service and Providers. When to use which?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, angular-services, angular-providers

I found that there are many answers online and here in stack overflow. But, none clarifies as to which one to use in which scenario as all three can perform the same set of functions?

Please clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: Also see this one in the official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 1):

A provider is a configurable service. If you create a `Foo` service with `provider()`, you are able to use a `FooProvider` in a `config()` block:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .provider('Foo', function () {
        ...
    })
    .config(function (FooProvider) {
        FooProvider.something('bar');
    })
    .run(function (Foo) {
        ...
    });
```

For a trivial example of what you might want to use this for, see [`$logProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$logProvider).

If you don't need a configurable `...Provider` for your service, the `factory()` or `service()` methods make it easier to create your service, since you don't need to do the complicated provider setup. **`factory`/`service` are merely shorthand convenience constructors if you don't need a provider.**

The difference between `factory` and `service` is that `factory` accepts a typical callback function, while `service` expects a "class" which it will instantiate with `new`. E.g.:

```
// Javascript "class"
function Foo() {
    ...
}
Foo.prototype.bar = ...;

angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .service('Foo', Foo)
    .factory('Bar', function () {
        ...
    })
    .run(function (Foo, Bar) {
        ...
    });
```

For more specifics on how to write a provider or provider-less service, see [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) and [the guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).